# Filling the rest of the page with CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I have three Divs on the page and they are absolute positioned. Lets call them leftDiv,middleDiv,rightDiv and middleDiv width is 900px which is okay but the left and right divs should fill the remaining the left and right parts respectively no matter what screen size is.

The reason why I use absolute positioning is because it is the only way to use height:100% to fill the page.

So how can I fill the remaining parts?

Of course these divs separate page into three pieces according to their names imply.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Since middleDiv is absolutely positioned, the size of leftDiv is fixed, unless I misunderstand your question.  Could you post some code/markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use absolute positioning for height. [This article](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/200.htm) explains as do many others.

You may then use float to accomplish the 3 column layout.

Answer (score 2):

Read this carefully: [In Search of the Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in CSS:

```
#leftDiv {
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}

#rightDiv {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```